# Design Help for making public class accessible from only on class

Tags: php

I have class

```
public Class Xyz   
{    
 const const1 = '1'
 const const2 = '2'
}
```

Can i do something that i can restrict that this class can be called only from class say Class2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make all functions and attributes of that class protected and class2 could extend class1.

Comment: Then you have to chain the classes... Class2 extend Class1 which extend the Class which Class2 extends at the moment...